# add custom value's to a function in another wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, function

see this code:

```html
function google_fonts() {

  $google_font_families = array(

'ABeeZee'                  => 'ABeeZee',
'Abel'                     => 'Abel',
'Abhaya Libre'             => 'Abhaya Libre',
'Abril Fatface'            => 'Abril Fatface',
  );

  return $google_font_families;

}
```

This function is in a WordPress theme
I want to add values to this function with the plugin.
how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change that function, you can add a WordPress filter, which you can hook into in the plugin and modify.

```
function google_fonts() {
$google_font_families = array(

    'ABeeZee'       => 'ABeeZee',
    'Abel'          => 'Abel',
    'Abhaya Libre'  => 'Abhaya Libre',
    'Abril Fatface' => 'Abril Fatface',
);

return apply_filters( 'theme_google_fonts',  $google_font_families );
```

}

You can find the docs for the filters here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/

---

A bit hacky solution:

You can also have a check like

```
if ( ! function_exists('google_fonts') ) {}
```

wrapping the function and then you can overwrite it in the plugin. Plugin code fires earlier, and I think that this could also work.